# Yet another IE image alignment issue: Float right inside right text-align wackiness

Tags: image, internet-explorer, png, alignment, css-float

I have an `<a>` element set to `display:block`, inside of which is some text and a png image. The `<a>` is set to `text-align:right` and the image is set to `float:right`.

It's fine in all browsers except IE 8( but haven't tried with earlier versions of IE), which displays the image below the text. If I do the old negative margin trick, it overlays the image on top of the text.

Note that I had to include the X-UA-Compatible meta tag to make the scripts work at all (jQuery).

I know IE has been tweaky with both png and float. It's possible to set margins and such to get them to look okay, but does anyone have thoughts about why they aren't just flowing together?

Note: I tried tests with text and the img in a regular div and it's the same issue.

Comment: Are you sure you have the image situated *before* the text in your source code?

Comment: You may also want to consider doctype.com (who are affiliated with stackoverflow) for this question.

Comment: @Pekka, that was it. Is this an IE quirk or a standard that other browsers forgive (and that I forgot)? Either way, many thanks!

Comment: you're welcome, but that behaviour should be the same in any browser. Strange! But maybe some other factor(s) played in.